# Adding Tags and its respective value to an object

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, dictionary

Let's assume we have a class called "Tag".

```
public class Tag
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public Type Type { get; private set; }

    public Tag(string name, string description, Type type)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Description = description;
        this.Type = type;
    }
}
```

An example of an instance of a Tag would be:

```
Tag weightTag = new Tag("Weight", "Weight of item in kg", typeof(double))
```

Next assume that I have another class which has a collection of these Tags which a value relevant to that object mapped to each individual tag in the collection.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }

    public Dictionary<Tag, object> Tags { get; private set; }

    public Item(string name, string description)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Description = description;

        this.Tags = new Dictionary<Tag, object>();
    }

    public void AddTag(Tag tag, object value)
    {
        Tags.Add(tag, value);
    }
}
```

I like this method due to the fact that you can take some predefined tags from some where and then just assign a value.

```
Tag buildDateTag = TagProvider.GetByName("BuildDate");
Tag weightTag = TagProvider.GetByName("Weight");

item.AddTag(buildDateTag, new DateTime(2013,12,06);
item.AddTag(weightTag, 10.5);
```

The downside to this method is that there will be a lot of boxing/unboxing.  For instance, if I have a collection of Item and I want to sum all the values of the tag corresponding to weight I'd have to do something like:

```
  double totalWeight = 0d;
  foreach (var item in items)
  {
      if (Tags.ContainsKey(weightTag))
      {
          totalWeight += (double)Tags[weightTag];
      }
  }
```

In this instance I happened to know that I'm going to cast to double so the only performance penalty was the unboxing.  However there may be instances where I will need to get the type of the object from the Type member in the Tag object in order to figure out what the type of the value object is.

My question is do you think there is a better way to architect this in order to get rid of the need to rely on using objects and unboxing everything every time I want to use a value?

And although this should probably be a different question, in this usage should Tag be a struct rather than a class?

Comment: Seems like you're directly going against the major benefit offered by .NET: strongly typed objects. Why do you need to support these random types in a collection vs strong types?

Comment: @DavidHaney I agree that you do lose a major benefit of strongly typed objects. This is something that smells more like Python than C#. How would you recommend amending this particular design to make it more strongly typed?

Comment: Can you better explain what your **goal** is in this design? If I know that I can give better opinions on how I might approach it.

Comment: @DavidHaney Basically this design is kind of an EAV approach.  To describe out architecture generically, we would like to be able to define what attributes an object has at run time via an xml file for example.  This approach allows us to do that. So let's say we have a product object as a base class.  If we want to create a new product with new attributes we either create a child class with the relevant members at compile time or use this method at run time.

Comment: But what does this buy you at runtime since you need business logic which I assume is compile-time currently in order to act upon these objects?

Comment: @DavidHaney Actually one of the benefits is that you can create an new object in run-time that you can run pre-compiled business logic against.  For instance, in the example above where you sum values that have the "Weight" tag any object you create that has that tag now can use that business logic.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you can use an interface that has some of the common properties for the objects that you are expecting to be as part of the objects that you can tag against.

In that case, you can accept any object that Implements your interface and hence, you will have a neat and a cleaner code

Sample :
class BuildDateTag : ITaggable
{
      int id;
      string name;
      double weight;
}

this way, you can have the tags defined inside the `Item` class from 
`public Dictionary<Tag, object> Tags { get; private set; }`
 
to `public Dictionary<Tag,ITaggable> Tags{get;set;}`

Consider this and post the queries and your feasibility w.r.to this suggestion